# iframe value passing

Tags: iframe

**Page 1**

```
< iframe id="ifrm1"  src="anything.com">  < /iframe>
```

**Page 2**

I want to use **page 1** iframe (ifrm1) src value "anything.com" in **Page 2**

please help me !!

Comment: you want to display  `anything.com` in page 2 or i am wrong? Plz clear your question.

Comment: i want to get page 1 ifrm1 src value in Page 2 .....plz help

Comment: hey shree-khanal u r right ..Plz send me code to to fetch page 1 ifrm1 src value in Page 2.....

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but may be it looks like this.

```
 if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        iframe fib= 
            (iframe )Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("ifrm1");
        if (ifrm1!= null)
        {
           fib.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its Correct ...but i am using HTML page ...so.can you send the code in java Script ..

Comment: Sorry D:) Java is far from me.Sorry.(:

Comment: hey, i am not talking about Java lang ..I am talking about scripting lang and can u tell me another way to get ifrm1 src value ..